# How to annotate the same value multiple times in django?

Tags: python, django, annotations

How to perform nested annotation on the same field.
Example:

Say you have two querysets that are a result of ***annotation***, where foo is the annotation field

```
qs1 = Assignmant.objects.filter(...).values('user_id').annotate(foo=Count('user_id'))
qs2 = Assignment.objects.filter(....).values('user_id').annotate(foo=Count('user_id'))

print("qs1 = ", qs1)
print("qs2 = ", qs2)

qs1 = [ {user_id:1, foo:30}, {user_id:2, foo:10} ]

qs2 = [ {user_id:1, foo:7}, {user_id:2, foo:5} ]
```

after the combination of the querysets, I need to annotate the sum of *foo*.

```
combined = qs1 | qs2
result = combined.annotate(Sum('foo'))


# The result of annotation will be

print(result)
[{user: 1, foo__sum: 37}, {user:2, foo__sum: 15}]
```

But when attempting to do so, I get an error:

```
FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('foo'): 'foo' is an aggregate
```

Comment: Can you provide more info about `qs1` and `qs2`. Likely this can be solved *without* a database `UNION`.

Comment: what kind of info do you need? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added some details